# I can't access Perforce edge server license

Tags: perforce, license-key

Our Perforce configuration has a commit server and 2 edge server.
There is no license in commit sever. We are using 20 free copies and use all license

Btw, we purchase 30 copies of Perforce license in one of edge server and set it up.

But in edge server user cannot create a client in edge sever. 
Edge sever admin check "p4 license  -u"
It shows 10 copies user available and clients only.

Why it shows usage of commit server users?How to separate this from commit server free license?
30 copies of license has to be used only edge server users.

Comment: Licensing of replica server configurations is complex, so you're best off contacting Perforce Technical Support for this. The simple answer is that your license covers your entire installation, not just one replica or Edge Server, and you install the license on the Commit Server to accomplish that.

Comment: we don't have commit sever license and we only have edge sever license. It is possible to edger server users can use their license?